# Why classical division ("/") for large integers is much slower than integer division ("//")?

Tags: python, division, integer-division, floor-division

I ran into a problem: The code was very slow for 512 bit odd integers if you use classical division for (p-1)/2. But with floor division  it works instantly. Is it caused by float conversion?

```
def solovayStrassen(p, iterations):    
    for i in range(iterations):         
        a = random.randint(2, p - 1)         
        if gcd(a, p) > 1:
            return False        
        first = pow(a, int((p - 1) / 2), p)    
        j = (Jacobian(a, p) + p) % p                            
        if first != j: 
            return False 
    return True
```

---

The full code

```
import random
from math import gcd

#Jacobian symbol
def Jacobian(a, n): 
    if (a == 0): 
        return 0 
    ans = 1 
    if (a < 0):         
        a = -a
        if (n % 4 == 3): 
            ans = -ans 
    if (a == 1): 
        return ans
    while (a): 
        if (a < 0): 
            a = -a
            if (n % 4 == 3):
                ans = -ans 
        while (a % 2 == 0): 
            a = a // 2 
            if (n % 8 == 3 or n % 8 == 5): 
                ans = -ans  
        a, n = n, a
        if (a % 4 == 3 and n % 4 == 3): 
            ans = -ans
        a = a % n
        if (a > n // 2): 
            a = a - n 
    if (n == 1): 
        return ans
    return 0 

def solovayStrassen(p, iterations):    
    for i in range(iterations):         
        a = random.randint(2, p - 1)         
        if gcd(a, p) > 1:
            return False        
        first = pow(a, int((p - 1) / 2), p)    
        j = (Jacobian(a, p) + p) % p                            
        if first != j: 
            return False 
    return True

def findFirstPrime(n, k): 
    while True:              
        if solovayStrassen(n,k):            
            return n
        n+=2    

a = random.getrandbits(512)
if a%2==0:
    a+=1    
print(findFirstPrime(a,100))
```

Comment: So what were the inputs?

Comment: Regardless of why, I wouldn't even consider using pure Python to implement a piece of high-performance code. Native libraries, or something like Cython, can perform thousands of times better than Python alone. Python is easy to read and write but it's not meant to be fast.

Comment: Random 512 bit odd number (you can get it by random.getrandbits(512)) and 2

Comment: Show exactly what you ran. `pow(a, (p - 1) / 2, p)` should have raised an exception: `TypeError: pow() 3rd argument not allowed unless all arguments are integers`

Comment: @RandomDavis but it works fine for "//"

Comment: @RandomDavis Isn't most of the work done in C here, though? Does Cython even do arbitrary-size ints (I'm not really familiar with it).

Comment: @TimPeters oh,  you can change to ```int((p-1)/2)```here (my bad). Also notice that it works fine with "/" if you use for example 64 bit number

Comment: @superbrain not sure about Cython. Also, each individual division might be done by C, but there's conversion and setup of the float objects required. The source code for Python's float division is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L593

Comment: @dolorexxx the implementation details of `//` and `/` surely differ quite a bit, which could explain the difference. `//` just happens to be faster because its implementation is a lot simpler, but both would certainly perform much better in native code.

Comment: @RandomDavis Are you sure the real reason for the speed difference isn't that `/` gives wrong results, affecting the algorithm negatively?

Comment: @superbrain I'm not sure, these are all guesses.

Comment: @superbrain: Yeah, random 512 bit value minus 1 divided by 2 is almost certainly going to undergo serious precision loss when converted to `float` (which only has 53 bits of integer precision). The algorithm might be faster, but the output will be *garbage*.

Comment: @RandomDavis Then I suggest [benchmarking](https://tio.run/##RY7NCsIwEITveYq9JYFisUUQxScRkYpb3UOSJV1Bnz7mB@ucdj6GneGPPIMf9xxTmmNwIOSQBMhxiAIRGSdRakF5MZxA//jk78EdwWfW7s0DpVw3ksXstoPVSuGb45ITZwVZ2kPfw6C71f0NeTEV2EwuSs0hwhXIl@cPNKM91FzBWHD93FiR5BJH3rS5Bjuog61dExxLhXSAjTVvU/oC) instead of guessing :-). As one should expect, `//` is a lot *slower*. Adding `int` to `/` makes *that* slower, but only by a bit. Not enough to explain the OP's "very slow" vs "instantly" difference, especially since that division is only a small part of the whole algorithm.

Comment: @superbrain You can substitute 512 bit odd number instead of p and 10 instead of second parameter for example.  And see that it takes no more than 3-5 seconds to perform integer division.In classical case it's about several minutes and maybe more (I unfortunately never waited XD)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, except they say the garbage is *slower* :-) (which is surprising, as I'd expect a wrong `first` to *more likely* differ from `j` and thus lead to an early `return`).

Comment: @superbrain I added full implementation code. Now you can test it

Comment: @superbrain fixed

Comment: @superbrain i'm sorry. Fixed again

Comment: Ok, now it runs, and as expected, it's the discussed "wrong results" / "garbage" issue.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments, `int((p - 1) / 2)` can produce garbage if `p` is an integer with more than 53 bits. Only the first 53 bits of `p-1` are retained when converting to float for the division.

```
>>> p = 123456789123456789123456789
>>> (p-1) // 2
61728394561728394561728394
>>> hex(_)
'0x330f7ef971d8cfbe022f8a'
>>> int((p-1) / 2)
61728394561728395668881408
>>> hex(_) # lots of trailing zeroes
'0x330f7ef971d8d000000000'
```

Of course the theory underlying the primality test relies on using *exactly* the infinitely precise value of `(p-1)/2`, not some approximation more-or-less good to only the first 53 most-significant bits.

As also noted in a comment, using garbage is likely to make this part return earlier, not later:

```
        if first != j: 
            return False
```

So why is it much slower over all? Because `findFirstPrime()` has to call `solovayStrassen()` many more times to find garbage that passes by sheer blind luck.

To see this, change the code to show how often the loop is trying:

```
def findFirstPrime(n, k):
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        if count % 1000 == 0:
            print(f"at count {count:,}")
        if solovayStrassen(n,k):            
            return n, count
        n+=2
```

Then add, e.g.,

```
random.seed(12)
```

at the start of the main program so you can get reproducible results.

Using floor (`//`) division, it runs fairly quickly, displaying

```
(6170518232878265099306454685234429219657996228748920426206889067017854517343512513954857500421232718472897893847571955479036221948870073830638539006377457, 906)
```

So it found a probable prime on the 906th try.

But with float (`/`) division, I never saw it succeed by blind luck:

```
at count 1,000
at count 2,000
at count 3,000
...
at count 1,000,000
```

Gave up then - "garbage in, garbage out".

One other thing to note, in passing: the `+ p` in:

```
        j = (Jacobian(a, p) + p) % p
```

has no effect on the value of `j`. Right? `p % p` is 0.